# Random image gets displayed when running game

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a main menu for a tower defence game. This is the code I've got so far.

Menu.py

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.examples.sprite_texture import img

pg.init()


class Menu():
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.img = img
        self.y = y
        self.x = x

    def draw(self, win):
        """draw image"""
        win.blit(self, img)
```

Main.py

```
import pygame as pg
from Menu import Menu

pg.init()

"""Displays screen"""
winWidth = 1280
winHeight = 720
size = (winWidth, winHeight)

win = pg.display.set_mode(size)


"""Load images and puts them into the correct size"""
bg_img = pg.image.load('Pic/td-gui/PNG/menu/bg.png')
bg_img = pg.transform.scale(bg_img,(1280 ,720))
setting_img = pg.image.load('Pic/td-gui/PNG/menu/button_settings.png')

clock = pg.time.Clock()

win.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
mainMenu = True
run = True
running = True
while run:
    clock.tick(30)
    pg.display.update()
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
            if not run:
                pg.quit()

    if mainMenu:
        settings_button = Menu(100, 100, setting_img)
        Menu.draw(setting_img)
```

[image]

These are not the images loaded at all! Once I exit this is then what appears:

[image]

This is the correct background image I want, however the settings button does not appear which is what I was trying to figure out before this issue came along. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The images are due to you blitting them from pygames example module, i.e. `from pygame.examples.sprite_texture import img` in your menu. Just remove it and make sure to call the blit function correctly.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()


class Menu:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.img = img
        self.y = y
        self.x = x

    def draw(self, win):
        """draw image"""
        win.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
```

Since you weren't using `self.img` in your blit function, you where actually blitting the global variable `img`, which was an example image you imported.

Answer (score 0):

The [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method has to arguments. The 1st argument is *Surface*, which needs to be drawn on the target, and the 2nd argument is the position. The position is either a pair of coordinates specifying the top left corner or a rectangle.

<s>`win.blit(self, img)`</s>

```py
win.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
```

---

`Menu` class

```py
class Menu():
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.img = img
        self.y = y
        self.x = x

    def draw(self, win):
        """draw image"""
        win.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
```